# How to get all possible values of entity field in Symfony 2.8 with Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, properties, entity, symfony-2.8

Let's assume I have entity `User` with property `country`. `country` is just a string and many users can have setted the same `country`. Then how to get list of all unique countries of all users? I'm using *Symfony2.8* with *Doctrine*.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the `DISTINCT` clause: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Here is how you can do it from a controller :

```
 $qb = $em->getRepository("MyBundle:Country")->createQueryBuilder("c");

 $countries = $qb->select("c")
    ->distinct(true)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

one liner:

```
$countries = $em->getRepository("MyBundle:Country")->findBy(array('distinct' => true));
```

However if i were you i would create a country entity wich is unique and make ManyToOne relationship between User and Country.that would be a much cleaner solution IMO